# Structure const error under template formatting

Tags: c++, templates

the fallowing code  tells me that o.days and days from constructor can't be solved, has anyone an idea why?

```
template <class T> struct Array{
    int days;
    T * M;
};
```

contructor of the class:

```
void constr(Array<Expe> &o){
        o=new Array;
        o->days = days;
        o->M = new Array[o->days];
}
```

EDIT (Luchian Grigore):

```
template <class T> struct Array{
int days;
T * M;
Array( int size ) : days(size), M(new int[size])
{
}
~Array()
{
   delete[] M;
}
};
```

when i try to init an array in main like this:

```
int main(){
//Main function of the program. no pre/ post condition.
Array <Expe> A;
```

error:

`enter code here`..\M.cpp:18:15: error: no matching function for call to 'Array::Array()'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array<Expe> &o` is a reference to an `Array<Expe>` object, not a pointer. If you **must** re-initialize it, the syntax is.

```
o = Array<Expe>();
```

and you access the members via `.`:

```
o.days = days;
o.M = new Array[o.days];
```

EDIT:

I remember the same code from yesterday. Why are you agains using proper constructors?

```
template <class T> struct Array{
    int days;
    T * M;
    Array( int size ) : days(size), M(new int[size])
    {
    }
    ~Array()
    {
       delete[] M;
    }
};
```

Comment: i remeber your code but sometimes it is hard to get used to stuff so fast at uni our teacher is pretty new as teacher and when it comes to teaching he is really weak and we have a lot to work... and as you can probably see i do everything by my own...
for example whay Array(int size)? the  size is constant... allways 31 poitions.

Comment: i used your code. i declared size as a global constat 31, but i get an error when i initializate a array. 
..\M.cpp:18:15: error: no matching function for call to 'Array<Expe>::Array()'

Comment: @BogdanMaier you're supposed to call the constructor with the parameter 32: `Array<Expe> arr(31);`.